# Why "spring.profiles.default" exists if "spring.profiles.active" can do the same?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Framework - in the current reference documentation exists the [Default Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-default) section. It has the following content

Starting with a code:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default")
public class DefaultDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql")
            .build();
    }
}
```

and the following content/explanation:

> If no profile is active, the `dataSource` is created.  You can see this as a way to provide a default definition for one or more beans.
> **If any profile is enabled, the default profile does not apply**.
>
> You can change the name of the default profile by using `setDefaultProfiles()` on the `Environment` or,
> declaratively, by using the `spring.profiles.default` property.

**Therefore**: Why from the beginning was not used directly `spring.profiles.active`? - it especially taking in consideration that is known that `spring.profiles.active` has more precedence and overrides by complete `spring.profiles.default` as indicated in bold above.

As summary:

- Why does `spring.profiles.default` exist if the same approach can be accomplished through `spring.profiles.active`?

Is not clear when is mandatory use the former over the latter - and taking the special consideration about the behavior of overriding if the latter is declared.

Just in case, the [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) javadoc does not contain some indication about this

Comment: FTR, the OP has cross-posted in the Spring Boot issue tracker, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30319